# Prefuse Java Bar Graphs

Tags: java, prefuse

Could someone tell me how I would be able to draw BarGraphs using [prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) with Java? Any resources that I could look into for learning how to draw them?

Comment: Prefuse looks like it never came out of beta and hasn't been updated for two and a half years. If you want to draw bar charts in Java have a look at JFreeChart. It's pretty much the defacto standard for open source Java charting and is still under active development.

Comment: The reason Prefuse hasn't been updated in several years is that the author has moved on and translated the idea to both Flash and Javascript since then.  It's still a very good piece of software despite the Beta label.

Comment: This is a duplicate question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793712/how-do-i-create-a-bar-chart-using-the-java-prefuse-library

Answer (score 2):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is an excellent graphing package, has a ton of [documentation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api.html), and is [regularly updated](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/).  I would recommend checking this out (unless there is some specific reason you are using prefuse).

Comment: Having used both, Prefuse is far superior to JFreeChart depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @Jay - Is that what you voted me down? Both answers are still valid and voting me down so your answer is higher is NOT what this site is about.

Comment: @Jay - In addition, at the time of this post, Prefuse wasn't even a valid piece of software (see Mark's comment above). Are you going to go back and retroactively vote down everybody else who commented correctly on a technology that has since changed?

Comment: @JasCav I voted you down because you didn't answer the question that was asked.  The author did not ask for software for creating bar charts.  I should have however added my comment as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @Jay - Well, if you look at Marks' answer (which he wrote the same time I wrote mine), Prefuse wasn't even a valid option. Hence, I was trying to provide another option for drawing bar graphs. Perhaps I should have specified. In either case, Prefuse may be great now, but in March of 2010 - it wasn't.

Comment: @JasCav, Prefuse was then and still is a very valid piece of software which is great for visualization.  Even though it is labeled beta, it works very well.  I've used both JFreeChart and Prefuse over the last four to five years.  They both have different strengths as well as different weaknesses.  If you just want simple charts and graphs and don't care about performance, filtering, or animation, JFreeChart is fine.  If you want to do more than that, Prefuse is a great choice.  I've had other visualization needs that neither one was suitable for.  That doesn't mean that they are not valid.